# Binary Search Tree copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, binary-search-tree, member

I am trying to write a copy constructor for my binary search but it is giving a segmentation fault for some reason.Here is my implementation:

```
template <typename T>
BTree<T>::BTree(const BTree<T>& other)
{
    copy_helper(this->root, other.root); 

} 

    template <typename T>
void BTree<T>::copy_helper(Node<T>* copy_to, const Node<T>* copy_from) const
{
    if(copy_from == NULL){
        copy_to = NULL; 
    } else{
        copy_to = new Node<T>; 
        copy_to->value = copy_from->value; 
        copy_helper(copy_to->left, copy_from->left); 
        copy_helper(copy_to->right, copy_from->right); 
        copy_helper(copy_to->parent, copy_from->parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: Just segmentation fault, it doesn't specify

Comment: It should have pointed you to the line that the segfault happened. Also, why are you passing a pointer called `copy_to` and immediately overwriting it? You might have some logic issues.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to pass `copy_to` by reference?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the pointer `cooy_to` is a local variable of the method `copy_helper.` As result changing the variable `copy_to` does not change the original pointer `this->root`.

You should pass the argument either by refernce or indirecdtly through a pointer.
For example

```
void BTree<T>::copy_helper(Node<T>* &copy_to, const Node<T>* copy_from) const
{
    if(copy_from == NULL){
        copy_to = NULL; 
    } else{
        copy_to = new Node<T>; 
        copy_to->value = copy_from->value; 
        copy_helper(copy_to->left, copy_from->left); 
        copy_helper(copy_to->right, copy_from->right); 
        copy_helper(copy_to->parent, copy_from->parent);
    }
}
```

In fact the data method should be declared either as a static function or a member function with one parameter `const Node<T>* copy_from`.

Answer (score 2):

If the member named `parent` is what its name suggests, `copy_helper(copy_to->parent, copy_from->parent)` will do terrible things. In particular, it will call `copy_helper` to copy the two children of the parent, and those copies will each copy their parent (again), and that copy will copy the two children (again), ad infinitum or until it crashes.

Copy **down** the tree only. Don’t go back up.

Comment: This was actually the problem, how can i fix that because i am supposed to copy it

Comment: After first two the calls to `copy_helper` do `copy_to~>left->parent = copy_to; copy_to~>right->parent = copy_to;`.

Answer (score 1):

For copy constructor (or assignment operator overload) for AVL Trees having 'parent' as one of the node pointer, you 'll need two separate steps:
First you deep copy the contents of all nodes (without touching the pointers), secondly, you pass the root of the newly constructed tree to a function that adjusts the pointers (in a recursive fashion).

E.g.

structure of node:

```
struct tree_node
{
    int key;
    std::string element;
    int balanceFactor;
    int height;

    tree_node* left;
    tree_node* right;
    tree_node* parent;

    tree_node() : key(0), element(""), balanceFactor(0), height(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(nullptr) {}
    explicit tree_node(int key, std::string element, tree_node* parent) : key(key), element(element), balanceFactor(0), height(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(parent) {}
    explicit tree_node(int key, std::string element) : key(key), element(element), balanceFactor(0), height(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(nullptr) {}

    void copyContent(tree_node* rhs)
    {
        //copies only the items/data/information
        //doesn't touch the poinetrs
        this->key = rhs->key;
        this->element = rhs->element;
        this->height = rhs->height;
        this->balanceFactor = rhs->balanceFactor;
    }
};
```

Now, here is the copy c-tor:

```
AVLTree::AVLTree(const AVLTree& rhs)
{
    this->ROOT = deepCopyContent(rhs.ROOT);
    adjustPointers(this->ROOT);
    this->numberOfNodes = rhs.numberOfNodes;
}
```

And the functions:

```
AVLTree::Node AVLTree::deepCopyContent(AVLTree::Node X)
{
    if (!X) return nullptr;
    else
    {
        Node _creation_ = new tree_node();
        _creation_->copyContent(X);

        _creation_->left = deepCopyContent(X->left);
        _creation_->right = deepCopyContent(X->right);
        return _creation_;
    }
}

void AVLTree::adjustPointers(AVLTree::Node X)
{
    if (!X) return;
    else
    {
        if (X->left) X->left->parent = X;
        if (X->right) X->right->parent = X;

        adjustPointers(X->left);
        adjustPointers(X->right);
    }
}
```

Hope, this helps.